# Coq: Bypassing the uniform inheritance condition

Tags: coq, coercion, subtype

I've trouble understanding the (point of the) [gauntlet](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/addendum/implicit-coercions.html?implicit%20coercions#identity-coercions) one has to pass to bypass the uniform inheritance condition (UIC). Per the instruction

> Let /.../ `f: forall (x₁:T₁)..(xₖ:Tₖ)(y:C u₁..uₙ), D v₁..vₘ` be a
>   function which does not verify the uniform inheritance condition. To
>   declare `f` as coercion, one has first to declare a subclass `C'` of `C`
>   /.../

In the code below, `f` is such a function:

```
Parameter C: nat -> Type.
Parameter D: nat -> Prop.
Parameter f: forall {x y}(z:C x), D y.
Parameter f':> forall {x y}(z:C x), D y. (*violates uic*)
Print Coercions. (* @f' *)
```

Yet I do not have to do anything except putting `:>` to declare it as a coercion. Maybe the gauntlet will somehow help to avoid breaking UIC? Not so:

```
Definition C' := fun x => C x.
Fail Definition Id_C_f := fun x d (y: C' x) => (y: C d). (*attempt to define Id_C_f as in the manual*)
Identity Coercion Id_C_f: C' >-> C.
Fail Coercion f: C' >-> D. (*Cannot recognize C' as a source class of f*)
Coercion f'' {x y}(z:C' x): D y := f z. (*violates uic*)
Print Coercions. (* @f' @f'' Id_C_f *)
```

The question: What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've trouble understanding the (point of the) gauntlet one has to pass to bypass the uniform inheritance condition (UIC).

Intuitively, the uniform inheritance condition says (roughly) "it's syntactically possible to determine every argument to the coercion function just from the type of the source argument".

The developer that added coercions found it easier (I presume) to write the code implementing coercions if the uniform inheritance condition is assumed.  I'm sure that a [pull request](https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/new/master) relaxing this constraint and correctly implementing more general coercions would be welcomed!

That said, note that there is a *warning* message (not an error message) when you declare a coercion that violates the UIC.  It will still add it to the table of coercions.  Depending on your version of Coq, the coercion might never trigger, or you might get an error message at type inference time when the code applying the coercion builds an ill-typed term because it tries to apply the coercion assuming the UIC holds when it actually doesn't, or (in older versions of Coq) you can get anomalies (see, e.g., bug reports [#4114](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/4114), [#4507](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/4507), [#4635](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/4635), [#3373](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/3373), and [#2828](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/2828)).

*That* said, here is an example where `Identity Coercion`s are useful:

```
Require Import Coq.PArith.PArith. (* positive *)
Require Import Coq.FSets.FMapPositive.

Definition lookup {A} (map : PositiveMap.t A) (idx : positive) : option A
  := PositiveMap.find idx map.

(* allows us to apply maps as if they were functions *)
Coercion lookup : PositiveMap.t >-> Funclass.

Definition nat_tree := PositiveMap.t nat.
Axiom mymap1 : PositiveMap.t nat.
Axiom mymap2 : nat_tree.

Local Open Scope positive_scope. (* let 1 mean 1:positive *)

Check mymap1 1. (* mymap1 1 : option nat *)
Fail Check mymap2 1.
(* The command has indeed failed with message:
Illegal application (Non-functional construction):
The expression "mymap2" of type "nat_tree"
cannot be applied to the term
 "1" : "positive" *)
Identity Coercion Id_nat_tree : nat_tree >-> PositiveMap.t.
Check mymap2 1. (* mymap2 1 : option nat *)
```

Basically, in the extremely limited case where you have an identifier which would be recognized as the source of an existing coercion if you unfolded its type a bit, you can use `Identity Coercion` to do that.  (You can also do it by defining a copy of your existing coercion with a different type signature, and declaring that a coercion too.  But then if you have some lemmas that mention one coercion, and some lemmas that mention the other, `rewrite` will have issues.)

There is one other use case for `Identity Coercion`s, which is that, when your source is not an inductive type, you can use them for *folding* and not just *unfolding* identifiers, by playing tricks with `Module`s and `Module Type`s; see [this comment on #3115](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/3115#issuecomment-337515689) for an example.

In general, though, there isn't a way that I know of to bypass the uniform inheritance condition.